# bash syntax for accessing an associative array with a value from a different associative array

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

Good morning,

I have here:

```
declare A- accocArray1=(["a01"]=1 ["a02"]=2 ["a03"]=3)
declare A- accocArray2=(["b01"]=1 ["b02"]=2 ["b03"]=3)
echo ${accocArray2["${accocArray1["a01"]}"]} ${accocArray2["${accocArray1["a02"]}"]} ${accocArray2["${accocArray1["a03"]}"]}
```

output:

```
1 2 3
```

I am having issues getting the syntax right in the "echo" statement. Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, it's `-A`, not `A-`. Secondly, `${accocArray1["a01"]}` yields `1`, but that is not a key in `accocArray2`. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `-A`, not `A-`;
2. You don't use the values of the other array, you use the keys. Use the actual values;
3. BTW, quoting the keys is not needed (but doesn't hurt).

```bash
#!/bin/bash
declare -A accocArray1=([a01]=b01 [a02]=b02 [a03]=b03)
declare -A accocArray2=([b01]=1 [b02]=2 [b03]=3)
echo "${accocArray2["${accocArray1[a01]}"]}" "${accocArray2["${accocArray1[a02]}"]}" "${accocArray2["${accocArray1[a03]}"]}"
```